# Ввод данных в приложение с разных устройств

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Как можно настроить в xcode ввод данных в tableView с разных устройств, сохранение этих данных на сервере и вывод всех данных на экран при запуске приложения?

Comment: а что такое с разных устройств?

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.